# Exchange Delegate Mailbox in Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app, exchange

Currently I am running Yosemite, I am trying to ascertain if it's possible to add a delegate mailbox to the mail.app. As of yet I have been unable to do so. Unfortunately I cannot have this particular mailbox as another account as it doesn't have the ability to be logged into.

Thanks,

Brendan

Comment: Delegate as what? been able to read the emails, respond to them, get it forwarded ?

Comment: as in my user account has been delegated full access to the shared mailbox, and i wish to attach it to mail.app so that i can view emails from the aforementioned shared mailbox

Comment: ok, got that, so why is it than not possible to log in to it?

Comment: because this is a shared mailbox it has no associated user account, as such nothing to login with

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that Mail.app does not have the ability to log into a shared (group) mailbox as I do not believe it understands the things that Microsoft did (very strange and awful things...) to IMAP to get the functionality that they wanted in Outlook.

For that you will need a copy of Outlook for the Mac, it may be available in the App store. not sure if it is free or not...

Comment: Just as to not confuse anyone, If it is an Exchange account, is is probably using MAPI which is not IMAP.

Comment: Indeed. Exchange works *similarly* to IMAP and may have even been based on or inspired by IMAP long ago, but it is a **very** different creature these days and the similarities are very basic surface features which, if you dig even a little, veers wildly from the way IMAP works.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and described by Apple in "[Mail (Yosemite): Subscribe to public and shared mailboxes](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19113?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)"

> If you have an IMAP account that provides access to public or shared
>   mailboxes, you can subscribe to them.
>
> 1. View account information for the
>      IMAP account that provides shared and public mailboxes.
> 2. In the Account Info window, click Subscription List.
> 3. In the list of available mailboxes, select the ones you want to
>      subscribe to, then click Subscribe.
>
> To unsubscribe from one or more mailboxes, select the mailboxes in the
>   Mail sidebar, then click Unsubscribe.

Comment: This only seems to apply for IMAP mailboxes, not Exchange ones.

Comment: Take it from a Jr Exchange admin, Exchange has the option to turn on IMAP (and POP) access. The trick comes in getting the admin to turn it on for you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the Accounts tab of Mail preferences has no hint of "Subscriptions" or delegation, and the gear icon at the bottom of the left pane in the GUI is now missing under Yosemite and El Capitan. The referral to the Account Info window under Yosemite in the link above is erroneous under 10.10.5.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your main Exchange as an Exchange account in order to have all other associated services such as calendar, contacts , ... configured at once.

To access a delegate / shared mailbox add an IMAP account using these parameters as inspired by https://uit.stanford.edu/service/sharedemail/applemail

Whilst adding an IMAP account in **Mail.app** > **Preferences** > **Accounts** :

1. Add **Other Mail Account…**:
2. Setup step #2:

   - Name: **John Doe**
   - Email Address: **your_account@domain.tld**
   - Password: **yourPassword**

If needed forcibly continue to next window by `alt / option` click `Sign In` button.

3. On the next windows where IMAP and SMTP server fields are showing up:

   - E-mail address: **shared_mailbox@domain.tld**
   - User Name: **your_account@domain.tld\shared_mailbox** < That's the trick to remember
   - Password: **yourPassword**
   - Fill in server settings: something like ***mail.domain.tld***
4. Finish the configuration…

You may later in the first tab of this delegate account change the Email address by your own if needed…