# Add shared Exchange Online Mailbox to Mail app

Tags: mac, mail.app, exchange, exchange-activesync

With Microsoft removing Basic Authentication in Exchange Online on 01.10.2022
(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online), they remove the ability to add a shared mailbox e.g. via IMAP or POP. (see e.g. [Exchange Delegate Mailbox in Mail.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178046/exchange-delegate-mailbox-in-mail-app) or https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250105787)

Several attempts with different email / user combinations failed either with the Mail app trying to add the sign in mail account (again) or with an 'Unable to verify user or password' error.

Is it possible to add shared exchange mailboxes to the Mail app? If so, how?

**EDIT:** I am running macOS Big Sur (11.6.6) and Mail.app version 14.0.

Comment: What version of macOS do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I've succeeded in adding a shared mailbox on Office365 in Apple Mail 16.0.

Steps to follow:

1. Go to **System Preferences** > **Internet Accounts**
2. Add a new account by selecting **Microsoft Exchange**
3. After adding the email address for the account I was prompted by Office365 OAuth and filled in the account and password

I am running macOS Monterey 12.6.

I have been accessing the shared mailbox via IMAP protocol until MS deprecated basic auth.

Comment: This still does not work for me on Big Sur with MacMail 14. In your step 3, I get asked for the password of the shared account, which does not exist. When changing the mail address, MacMail tries to add the Mail account with which I have to use for shared mailbox authentication. This mail account is already added...

Comment: Indeed when adding the « delegated account » | « shared folder » using it's E-mail then choosing « Sign-in with another user account » and typing credentials of my account it's simply connecting to my account not the « delegated » | « shared » one.

Comment: Looks like the only way to overcome that issue whilst still using Mail.app is to Proxy IMAP requests through another process that implements OAUTH2 authentication. Eg. https://github.com/simonrob/email-oauth2-proxy 

Apple shamefully hasn't yet added that feature even in the currently latest MacOS Ventura…